# JavaScript - Character counter for multiple textareas

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form on my website with several different textareas.

HTML/PHP

```php
foreach ($bla as $blabla) {
  .... other php-code (not relevant) ....
  echo '<textarea id="textarea['.$blabla["ID"].']" name="textarea" maxlength="1000" onKeyUp="countChars(\'textarea['.$blabla["ID"].']\',\'count\',\'{CHAR}\',1000);""></textarea>';
  echo '<span id="counter">1000</span>';
}
```

JS:

```
function countChars(entrance, exit, text, characters) {
  var entranceObj = document.getElementById(entrance);
  var exitObj = document.getElementById(exit);
  var length = characters - idObj.value.length;
  if (length <= 0) {
    length = 0;
    text =
      '<span class="disable" style="color: red;">' +
      text +
      '</span>';
    entranceObj.value = entranceObj.value.substr(0, characters);
  } else if (length <= 20) {
    text =
      '<span style="color: red">' +
      text +
      '</span>';
  }
  exitObj.innerHTML = text.replace("{CHAR}", length);
}
```

This code works. However, the counter only works for one textarea. Any ideas why it isn't working on all?

Comment: please note, html elements must have a unique id, currently you are assigning `id="textarea"` to each element created in your loop.

Comment: hence, this `var entranceObj = document.getElementById(entrance);` will always refer to the first textarea.

Comment: you can assign different ids using a counter, like this: `foreach ($bla as $blabla) { $i++; echo '<textarea id="textarea_"' . $i . ' name=".....`

Comment: @GrafiCode I've tried giving it different id's using "id=textarea[$blabla["ID"]]". I just don't know how to move on from there.

Comment: ah ok then also modify this `onKeyUp="countChars(\'textarea[' . $blabla["ID"] . '] \', ....`

Comment: @GrafiCode Tried that too. It doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: All textareas have the [same id](/q/5611963). This means you can only find the first one through `document.getElementById('textarea')`. And the [same name](/q/452066). This might also not be intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give unique identifiers for each textarea and counter span. Here's your PHP code modified to match (using heredoc string delimiters to keep it more readable):

```
foreach ($bla as $key => $blabla) {
    echo <<<BLA
<textarea id="textarea_{$key}" name="textarea_{$key}" maxlength="1000"
 onKeyUp="countChars('{$key}','{CHAR}',1000);""></textarea>
<span id="counter_{$key}">1000</span>
BLA;
}
```

If the keys in your array aren't usable as above, then add a counter variable that you increment on each iteration instead, and use that as the key. You'll notice a difference in the `countChars` function call, where we just pass the key, or the unique part of `textarea_` and `counter_` to your Javascript function.

Then, the Javascript function is modified to match:

```
function countChars(itemId, text, characters) {
    var entranceObj = document.getElementById('textarea_'+itemId);
    var exitObj = document.getElementById('counter_'+itemId);
    // ...
}
```

We generate the actual IDs for both the textarea and the counter on the basis of the unique bit. Now, you *could* also pass the full IDs in two arguments, but it's basically just redundant bulk. It's cleaner to keep function signatures minimal and regenerate patterns like this.

Comment: Markus and GrafiCode. I managed to solve it now with both your help. Thanks alot!

Comment: @leo great. P.S. Passing `{CHAR}` as the `text` function argument isn't really needed when your `replace` is hard-wired to only replace `{CHAR}` anyway. You could just drop the `text` argument and `replace` altogether and simply do `var text = '<span style="color: red">' + length  + '</span>';` by the looks of it.

Comment: @leo You can skip setting `onKeyUp` in PHP entirely and add the eventhandlers in JS by `Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')).forEach(ta=>ta.addEventListener('keyup', countChars))`. Then you can save the querySelector entirely and [get](/q/1803195) the textarea via `var entranceObj = this`  